# Calling Firebase.initializeApp() returns '(PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null))'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

My app is a Chating App, I am adding a new registered user to firebase using Firebase_auth. But when i am initializing the app in the main() function it is showing an exception. PlatformException (PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)).

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(FlashChat());
}
```

This is my main() function.

Below is my pubspec.yaml file :

```
name: flash_chat_app
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.6 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.2
  firebase_core: ^2.12.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.6.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.7.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
  - images/
```

I tried the other solutions given to this problem but none is working for me.
I tried flutter clean and flutter pub get.
This is my output of flutter pub outdated :

```
Showing outdated packages.
[*] indicates versions that are not the latest available.

Package Name              Current   Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest

direct dependencies: all up-to-date.

dev_dependencies: all up-to-date.

transitive dependencies:
async                     *2.9.0    *2.9.0      *2.9.0      2.11.0
boolean_selector          *2.1.0    *2.1.0      *2.1.0      2.1.1
characters                *1.2.1    *1.2.1      *1.2.1      1.3.0
collection                *1.16.0   *1.16.0     *1.16.0     1.17.2
js                        *0.6.4    *0.6.4      *0.6.4      0.6.7
matcher                   *0.12.12  *0.12.12    *0.12.12    0.12.16
material_color_utilities  *0.1.5    *0.1.5      *0.1.5      0.5.0
meta                      *1.8.0    *1.8.0      *1.8.0      1.9.1
path                      *1.8.2    *1.8.2      *1.8.2      1.8.3
source_span               *1.9.0    *1.9.0      *1.9.0      1.10.0
stack_trace               *1.10.0   *1.10.0     *1.10.0     1.11.0
stream_channel            *2.1.0    *2.1.0      *2.1.0      2.1.1
string_scanner            *1.1.1    *1.1.1      *1.1.1      1.2.0
test_api                  *0.4.12   *0.4.12     *0.4.12     0.5.2
vector_math               *2.1.2    *2.1.2      *2.1.2      2.1.4

transitive dev_dependencies:
lints                     *2.0.1    *2.0.1      *2.0.1      2.1.0
all dependencies are up-to-date.
```

I also tried adding the requied code to my build.gradle file.
This is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also added the following code to my app level build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')

  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

These are the content of my current app level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I add options parameter and it works fine to me

`await Firebase.initializeApp(options: const FirebaseOptions(apiKey:'Your API key',appId:'mobilesdk_app_id',messagingSenderId:'project_number',projectId:'project_id'));`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I just restarted VSCode whole and now it doesn't show any error.